# Check if value in column is TRUE at any point in different column in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to check if the values in `Col1` at any point are TRUE in `Col2`. The result should be as presented in the `Result` column below.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Col1   + Col2  + Result +
+ Name 1 + TRUE  + TRUE   +
+ Name 1 + FALSE + TRUE   +
+ Name 2 + FALSE + FALSE  +
+ Name 2 + FALSE + FALSE  +
+ Name 3 + TRUE  + TRUE   +
+ Name 4 + FALSE + FALSE  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

How can I do this in Excel 2016?

Comment: You want to check the `VLOOKUP` function.  I don't use excel any more, so can't build an example for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is using COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,A1,$B$1:$B$6,"TRUE")>0
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about **SUMIF** which follows the same logic :)

Comment: @TerryW but what would you sum?

Comment: good point actually I would use SUMPRODUCT: `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$6=A1)*(--($B$1:$B$6)))>0` as the `--` conversion is not allowed in SUMIF